# Should I implement a struct's variables within the constructor of its containing class?

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, linked-list, default-constructor

I have a header file with a class called 'list' and a struct called 'node' within the private part of that class. Together, this class and struct will make up a doubly threaded list of winery objects (winery being it's own class). What I'm wondering is if it would be best to implement and de-implement the node struct's variables within the list constructor and deconstructor
(like this):

```
list::list()
{
    struct node
    {
        item = winery::winery()
        nextByName = nullptr;
        nextByRating = nullptr;
    };
    headByName = nullptr;
    headByRating = nullptr;
}
list::~list()
{
    struct node
    {
        delete item;
        delete nextByName;
        delete nextByRating;
    };
    delete headByName;
    delete headByRating;
}
```

if it would be better to implement and de-implement them separately
(like this):

```
list::node::node()
{
    item = winery::winery()
    nextByName = nullptr;
    nextByRating = nullptr;
}
list::node::~node()
{
    delete item;
    delete nextByName;
    delete nextByRating;
}
```

or if I should something else? I've looked online, and in my textbooks, but there really is no clear answer on this. I would really appreciate your guys help, and if you could explain why your solution is the best (if it is the best), I would be extremely grateful. I just started learning C++ a few months ago after all.

By the way, this is what my list.h file looks like:

```
#include "winery.h"

class list
{
public:
    list();
    ~list();
    void addWinery();
    void removeWinery();
    void displayByRating() const;
    void displayByName() const;
    void searchByName() const;
private:
    struct node
    {
        winery item;
        node * nextByName;
        node * nextByRating;
    }; 
    node * headByName;
    node * headByRating;
};
```

Comment: Why not use the C++ Standard Template Library and its great collection of containers and algorithms?

Comment: You need to understand what `new` and `delete` actually do before writing any code. First rule is never to `delete` something that hasn't been created by `new`. The long list of errors that any compiler will give you about the above code should warn you as well. Also, "Implement" doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @RichardChambers Good point, but I suspect OP'snot allowed to!. Also is there any list-type container that allows ordering by two different criteria?

Comment: @Roddy My compiler throws an error when I delete those nodes within the list constructor and deconstructor. When I delete those elements separately, my constructor only throws the error for the `delete item;`. Do you know why this is? Can you explain why I don't need to delete the winery item? Should I call the winery deconstructor there?

Comment: @ Roddy Also, what word should I use in place of 'implement'? Construct seems like it's not the right word either; is it?